# git clone works, push fails the same url from php

Tags: git

I'm running the following commands:

```
$Command = "https://user:password@mydomain.com/MyGit/code.git";
exec("git clone " . $Command);

//copy a file into the cloned repository
exec("git commit -am \"files added\"");
exec("git push " . $Command);
```

All works fine except for the last line that results in this error:

> remote: Invalid username or password.
>
> fatal: Authentication failed for `https://user:password@mydomain.com/MyGit/code.git`

I wonder what is going on since the same user-password combo works for cloning and I am the owner of the repo so read/write access is granted for the "user".

I do not want to setup an external secure key, I just would like the plain simple user-password authentication over HTTPS.

Comment: does cloning from https:// mydomain.com/MyGit/code.git (without username and password) work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying doing the git push using:

```
exec("git push origin master");
```

Basically, the URL address is saved as a reference to the origin repo in the `.git/config` file of the project.